# In Emacs, how do I use directory local variables for remote projects?

Tags: emacs, project, tramp

I'm using TRAMP to connect to a remote server and I wanted to use some directory local variables. What are my options? Should I use emacs-server and do it that way, or should I add the directory local variables to my .emacs file? Is there a way to force TRAMP to look for the .dir-locals.el file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Emacs 24.3 or later, see legoscia's answer.

For earlier versions, you can use the following workaround from [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables):

> We can advise `‘hack-dir-local-variables’` to work around this, if you
>   are willing to incur the associated performance cost (which can be
>   relatively minimal in some situations).
>
> ```el
> ;; Enable directory local variables with remote files. This facilitates both
> ;; the (dir-locals-set-class-variables ...)(dir-locals-set-directory-class ...)
> ;; and the .dir-locals.el approaches.
> (defadvice hack-dir-local-variables (around my-remote-dir-local-variables)
>   "Allow directory local variables with remote files, by temporarily redefining
> `file-remote-p' to return nil unconditionally."
>   (flet ((file-remote-p (&rest) nil))
>   ad-do-it))
> (ad-activate 'hack-dir-local-variables)
> ```

If using directory classes instead of a `.dir-locals.el` file, you would set the class using a normal tramp path. e.g.:

```el
 (dir-locals-set-class-variables
  'read-only
  '((nil . ((buffer-read-only . t)))))

 (dir-locals-set-directory-class
  "/ssh:(user)@(host):/path/to/dir" 'read-only)
```

Answer (score 12):

If you're using Emacs 24.3 or later, set `enable-remote-dir-locals` to t.