# restrict .dir-locals.el searching walk through subdirectories

Tags: emacs

a quick question in case someone has done this before:

I'm trying to stop Emacs from trying to recursively open `.dir-locals.el` under all parent subdirectories when opening a file. I have found how to stop it completely (by forcing all files to be remote - the opposite of this: [In Emacs, how do I use directory local variables for remote projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654456/in-emacs-how-do-i-use-directory-local-variables-for-remote-projects)) but I would like to allow access to at least the `.dir-locals.el` in the current directory of the file Emacs is editing, or implement a similar solution to the `GIT_CEILING_DIRECTORIES` variable (where git stops looking for `.git` after reaching a specific directory defined in this variable).

I have no experience with Emacs unfortunately.

EDIT: A sample from `strace` when I run `emacs testfile` in `/tmp/test/a/b/c/d`.

```
stat("/tmp/test/a/b/c/d/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
stat("/tmp/test/a/b/c/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
stat("/tmp/test/a/b/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
stat("/tmp/test/a/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) 
stat("/tmp/test/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/tmp/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)  
stat("/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This is not happening for example in `/home/user/a/b/c/d`, and it stops looking when it reaches `/home/user`.

EDIT2: Some more information regarding why I'm looking for a solution to this:
the directory `/mnt/groups/` is automounting directories such as `/mnt/groups/project1`, `/mnt/groups/workA`, `/mnt/groups/final_presentation`, where users are allowed to work. When a user launches Emacs inside e.g. `/mnt/groups/project1/documentation`, Emacs searches for `.dir-locals.el`, `.bzr`, `.git`, `_MTN` etc through every parent subdirectory until it reaches `/`. I've used `vc-ignore-dir-regexp` (in a file in `site-start.d`, so it would apply globally) to stop it from looking for version control related directories after `/mnt/groups`, but I cannot stop it from doing the same for `.dir-locals.el`. While I've blacklisted `.dir-locals.el` in the automounter (so a solution is partially in place for my problem), I would prefer to stop Emacs altogether from going through all parent subdirectories. I tried setting `locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp` but it didn't seem to affect looking for `.dir-locals.el`, unless it is somehow clashing with `vc-ignore-dir-regexp`. Unfortunately, as I mentioned, I have no experience with Emacs (I'm not using it myself) so I wasn't able to understand how to program anything more advanced.

Comment: Could you describe what you're doing in more detail, e.g. step by step, explaining what you'd like to be able to do here or there along the way?

Comment: "stops looking ... after reaching a specific directory" -- just put an empty `.dir-locals.el` file in that directory?

Comment: @phils I would like to avoid placing the `.dir-locals.el` as the directory in question  that I don't want Emacs to look for it is where automounting occurs.

Comment: @Drew I want to avoid this from happening:
`stat("/tmp/test/a/b/c/d/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`  
`stat("/tmp/test/a/b/c/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`  
`stat("/tmp/test/a/b/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`  
`stat("/tmp/test/a/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`  
`stat("/tmp/test/.dir-locals.el", 0x7ffe15dd1ee0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Put any useful info in the question, not in comments. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: If you prefer to disable them entirely, you can customize `enable-dir-local-variables`; otherwise you're probably going to need to redefine or advise `dir-locals-find-file`.  Advice to let-bind `locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp` based on `default-directory` would probably do the trick (but might be awkward to implement).

Comment: You could advise `dir-locals--all-files` (the `--` means "private function", so it may break on Emacs updates).  You can make it return `nil` for directories you don't want to search.  Read the docs for it and `locate-dominating-file`.  You should put more details in your question, like what are the exact criteria to exclude searching a directory.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed adding a regexp in `locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp`. I wasn't providing the correct format for regexp in Emacs.

Adding the following in a .el file in `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d/`:

```
(setq locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp (concat locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp "\\|\\`/mnt\\/groups\\/\\'" ))
```

does the trick.